# Multiple JSON instances for one Persistent entity

Tags: haskell, persistent, servant

I am using Servant and Persistent together. I have a `User` entity and I would like to know if it is possible to respond with just a subset of its fields, depending on the context.

Let's consider the following two endpoints:

```
type UserAPI = "user"
            :> Capture "username" Username
            :> Get '[JSON] (Entity User)

type ProfileAPI = "profiles"
                :> Capture "username" Username
                :> Get '[JSON] (Entity User)

type AppAPI = UserAPI :<|> ProfileAPI
```

Here's our `User` model:

```
share [mkPersist sqlSettings, mkMigrate "migrateAll"] [persistLowerCase|
User json sql=users
    username  Text
    email     Text
    password  Text
    token     Text
    bio       Text Maybe default=NULL
    image     Text Maybe default=NULL
    createdAt UTCTime default=now()
    updatedAt UTCTime Maybe default=NULL

    UniqueUser username email
    deriving Show
|]
```

When a `GET /user` request arrives, let's say we just want to respond with `email` and `token` for authentication purposes. On the other hand, when a `GET /profile/:username` request arrives, we want to respond with just `username`, `bio` and `image`.

How can we accomplish this? Thanks.

---

**Update:** I believe it is possible to "convert" between Persistent types and Servant request types by using different records for a specific table. For instance, one is used by Persistent, and the other is used as an interface with the client. However, this may require a function to convert between the two. As the logic grows, I presume things will become cumbersome.

Moreover, I was thinking that defining ToJSON and FromJSON instances could do the trick, but I can't wrap my head around it.

Comment: @AlexisKing I edited my post addressing you comment. Did I miss the point? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Why do you want multiple instances for the same datatype? Why don't you create separate datatypes for the data you'd like each handler to return, and `ToJSON` instances for each?

```
type UserAPI = "user"
            :> Capture "username" Username
            :> Get '[JSON] UserEmailAndToken

type ProfileAPI = "profiles"
                :> Capture "username" Username
                :> Get '[JSON] UserNameBioAndImage

type AppAPI = UserAPI :<|> ProfileAPI
```

Then you'd define `UserEmailAndToken` and `UserNameBioAndImage` (which should be very easy), write `ToJSON` instances for each, along with trivial functions mapping between `User` and these types.